# ECDSA IN CONTIKI ERROR

Tags: contiki

Im trying to compile this file ecc-sign.c authored by you.

/home/user/Desktop/contiki-2.7/examples/cc2538-common/pka/ecc-sign.c

but what im getting is the errors below,

```
  LD        ecc-sign.z1
ecc-sign.co: In function `process_thread_ecdsa_sign_test':
ecc-sign.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `pka_init'
ecc-sign.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `ecc_dsa_sign'
ecc-sign.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `ecc_compare'
ecc-sign.c:(.text+0x122): undefined reference to `ecc_compare'
ecc-sign.c:(.text+0x148): undefined reference to `pka_disable'
```

here is the make file in folder /home/user/Desktop/contiki-2.7/examples/cc2538-common/pka/

```
CONTIKI_PROJECT = ecc-ecdh ecc-sign ecc-verify
all: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT)
CONTIKI = ../../..
include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
```

Comment: did you find any solution? I have the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

What is the hardware platform you are using?

> LD        ecc-sign.z1

If it's the Z1, the compilation fails, because this is example is based on the CC2538 chip, which supports hardware acceleration for ECDSA.
The Z1's MSP430 however doesn't and that's why it fails.